# How to access a structure externally?

Tags: c++, data-structures

**Decision.h**

```
typedef struct DST
{
    float salary;
    float x1;
    float x2; 
};

struct DST person;

decision()
{  
    std::vector<std::vector<DST>> person(300);
    for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++) 
    person[i].resize(300); 
    //And made some computation to save the data in 2d structure person
}
```

**check.h**

```
//In this header I want to access person structure

extern DST person;

check()
{
    for(int i=0; i<300; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<300;j++)
        {
            conf[0]+= person[j][i].salary;
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting following error:

```
error C2676: binary '[' : 'DST' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
error C2228: left of '.salary' must have class/struct/union
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Make your `check`  a method (or member function) of your `struct DST` (which should become a `class`). Read much more your C++ programming language book.

Comment: well struct doesnt need to become a class. the only difference is default member access

Comment: You're telling the compiler `person` is of type `DST`, so why do you expect to be able to index into it using `operator[]`. Declaring a `vector` within a function doesn't magically transform the type of a global variable, just because the two happen to have the same name. And you shouldn't be defining variables in header files. But most of all, what you need to do is read a good book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to extract from your code what you actually want to do and give you a few guidelines as to how you should do it.

Firstly, if you are writing C++ (and not plain old C) you can leave out the typedef and explicit statement of DST as a struct. That is your first code should be:

```
struct DST {
   float salary;
   float x1;
   float x2; 
};
```

Next as Praetorian mentions in the comment above, you need to give your functions access to your data. This could be done using a global variable as you have tried to do, but this is in general a bad idea.

The recommended practice is to declare the variables inside a function or class and pass it to other functions as a parameter as needed.

A simple example:

```
// A function working on a DST
void printDST(DST &aDST) {
    cout << "Salary: " << aDST.salary 
         << "\nx1: " << aDST.x1 
         << "\nx2: " << aDST.c2 
         << endl;
}

int main() {
    DST person = { 10000.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f}; // Declare and initialize a DST object.

    //Pass this person to a function
    printDST(person);

    return 0;
}
```

You should probably familiarize yourself with functions and the core elements of C++ before you venture off into much more complex examples. But for completeness here is a function that summarize the salaries of a single vector of DST's (ignore the `const` for now.):

```
double sum_DST_salaries( const std::vector<DST> & dstVec ) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dstVec.size(); i++) { // Using .size() is preferable 
          sum += dstVec[i].salary;            // to hard coding the size as it updates
    }                                         // nicely if you decide to change the size
    return sum;
}
```

To use this function you would do something like:

```
int main() {
    // Create vector of DSTs
    std::vector<DST> employees(300);

    // Initialize them somehow....

    // Calculate combined salaries:
    double total_salaries = sum_DST_salaries(employees);

    // Print it:
    cout << "Total salaries are: " << total_salaries << endl;

    return 0;
}
```